# Hiding opaque NSView in transparent NSWindow leaves behind shadow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, transparent, nswindow, shadow

What's the trick to clearing out shadows left behind after hiding an opaque NSView inside a transparent NSWindow?

Answer (score 0):

Send the window [an `invalidateShadow` message](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/invalidateShadow).

Answer (score -1):

Does

```
[[view superview]setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

help (`view` being the view you hid)?